# Python Error: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python

I don't understand this error OR what it means. I will paste my code underneath, but I don't think it is really relevant; I just want to understand this error.

It's just a bit of code to add up the letters in all numbers 1 - 1000 (inclusive)

```
def number_translator(x):
    if x == 1:
        return 3
    elif x == 2:
        return 3
    elif x == 3:
        return 5
    elif x == 4:
        return 4
    elif x == 5:
        return 4
    elif x == 6:
        return 3
    elif x == 7:
        return 5
    elif x == 8:
        return 5
    elif x == 9:
        return 4
    elif x == 10:
        return 3
    elif x == 11:
        return 6
    elif x == 12:
        return 6
    elif x == 14:
        return 8
    elif x == 15:
        return 7
    elif x == 16:
        return 7
    elif x == 17:
        return 9
    elif x == 18:
        return 8
    elif x == 19:
        return 8
    elif x == 20:
        return 6
    elif x == 30:
        return 6
    elif x == 40:
        return 5
    elif x == 50:
        return 5
    elif x == 60:
        return 5
    elif x == 70:
        return 7
    elif x == 80:
        return 6
    elif x == 90:
        return 6

count = 0
for element in range(1, 1001):
    if element < 21:
        count += number_translator(element)              # for numbers 1 - 20
    elif 20 < element < 100:
        count += number_translator(int(str(element)[0]) * 10) + number_translator(int(str(element)[1]))  # for numbers 21 through 100
    elif element % 100 == 0 and element != 1000:
        count += number_translator(int(str(element)[0])) + 7   # for numbers divisible by 100, but not 1000
    elif element == 1000:
        count += 11                                          # just for 1000
    elif element % 100 < 20:
        count += number_translator(int(str(element)[0])) + 10 + number_translator(int(str(element)[1:3]))      # now I add in numbers like 101 - 120, 201 - 220, etc.
    else:
        count += number_translator(int(str(element)[0])) + 10 + number_translator(int(str(element)[1]) * 10) + number_translator(int(str(element)[2])) # now the rest( 121, 122, 123, 225, 256, 984, etc.)

print(count)
```

Comment: do you have default case for this long function? if you missed one number the function will return None and will likely produce this error. Also, this is a really inefficient way to write this translation thing. Just use an array.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

When none of the `if` test in `number_translator()` evaluate to true, the function returns `None`. The error message is the consequence of that.

Whenever you see an error that include `'NoneType'` that means that you have an operand or an object that is `None` when you were expecting something else.

Answer (score 7):

In your giant `elif` chain, you skipped 13. You might want to throw an error if you hit the end of the chain without returning anything, to catch numbers you missed and incorrect calls of the function:

```
...
elif x == 90:
    return 6
else:
    raise ValueError(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error with '/' operand while processing images. I discovered the folder included a text file created by the 'XnView' image viewer. So, this kind of error occurs when some object is not the kind of object expected.

Comment: Suggestions, hints, insights, links, etc, that are not Complete Answers as defined by SO are greatly welcomed & valued *as Comments*. The distinction between comments & answers is a trait of SO enabling this platform work as intended, which is different from forums. Visit https://www.stackoverflow.com/help for more information. While your suggestion, as is, provides a hint, "some object" is not specific enough to OP's current code to *solve* the issue. It does give an helpful idea of what to look for, however. You can edit your answer to be more specific, or post it as-is as a comment.