# How to get output value of Nonetype variable as integer

Tags: python, integer, typeerror, nonetype, operands

Please need help.
I want to pick an output value from a nonetype variable and subtract it from an integer variable

i wrote down an input box but am not able to pick the value from the assigned variable as integer type

The algorithm image found below.
Thank you

[unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'NoneType'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJrAl.png)

Comment: No, you don't want to do that. What you want to do is to solve your bug, so that your second operand is not `None` anymore. Currently it is. That is it does not contain the `user_age` you are expecting. It is not a typing problem (that would involve a conversion of some sort, to get `user_age` in the correct type): the age is not there at all. `user_age` is `None`, and not a number.

Comment: And the reason for that is because `user_age` is the return value of a `print`. And `print` returns None. It as no reason to return one of the values it is printing, namely the result of the `input` subcall

Comment: Another note: please avoid [posting images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "pick out" values from a NoneType. NoneType is None, nothing, null.

You're not storing "user_age", you need to remove print. Print doesn't return anything.

```py
user_age = input("what is your current age")
user_age = int(user_age) # convert string to int

age_limit = 90
age = age_limit - user_age
```

Also, you should google your error first before submitting a new one. This has already been answered multiple times. [Python Error: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110282/python-error-unsupported-operand-types-for-int-and-nonetype)